# libcurl drops the requests with this Error Pipe is full, skip (5)

Tags: c, curl, libcurl

Libcurl behaves fine but when I send a lot of requests and while enabling the debug dumps these errors. I have tried to find answers online but there is no reference to this error.

```
* No connections available in cache
* No connections available.
* Found bundle for host 10.0.0.31: 0x555555d91b50 [can pipeline]
* Pipe is full, skip (5)
* Pipe is full, skip (5)
* Pipe is full, skip (5)
* Pipe is full, skip (5)
* Pipe is full, skip (5)
* Pipe is full, skip (5)
* Pipe is full, skip (5)
* Pipe is full, skip (5)
```

Has anybody faced this issue before, what might cause this and how to solve this. Any help will be appreciated.

From the code I have set CURLMOPT_PIPELINING on

```
curl_multi_setopt(g.multi, CURLMOPT_MAX_TOTAL_CONNECTIONS, 512L);
curl_multi_setopt(g.multi, CURLMOPT_PIPELINING, 1L);
```

Syed.

Comment: In 7.65.0 pipelining support was removed from libcurl largely because it was unreliable. I would advice to switch it off.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I did and this along with a double free crash (https://github.com/pycurl/pycurl/issues/394) issue is not seen.